# Can members of a dev project use different yarn versions?

Tags: yarnpkg

Can developers of a project use different yarn versions, will it cause conflicts? How to make sure that any member uses the same version?

Comment: Yes, dvelopers can use different versions, and yes, there cases that can cause conflicts. You can set version ranges in `package.json`, and you can set a version range that contains only one specific version, e.g. `>=1.2.3 <=1.2.3` allows only version `1.2.3`.